# Método POST recebendo objeto vázio. C#

Tags: c#, api, restful, postman

Tenho uma controller com um método POST que sempre recebe o parâmetro nulo.
Estou mandando o JSON pelo postman.

Já tentei por a classe como parâmetro, já tentei por string como parâmetro e em ambos os casos está deixando ele nulo;

Segue a controller:

```
using API_Shop.AppComponents.Model;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace API_Shop.Controllers
{
    public class TesteController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/Teste
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET: api/Teste/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST: api/Teste
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            Teste tt = new Teste();
            tt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Teste>(value);
            throw new Exception(tt.Texto.ToString());
        }

        // PUT: api/Teste/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE: api/Teste/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Esta exception está dando 'Valor não pode ser nulo'.
O outro teste informando o tipo do parâmetro 'Teste' também está recebendo nulo. No caso, a exception que é lançada é de referência nula de objeto.

Segue JSON enviado pelo POSTMAN:

```
{
  "Teste":{
  "texto":"teste de post para controller"
   }
}
```

Já teste o GET e funciona normalmente.

Alguém pode me dar uma mãozinha com isso? Como faço para ele pegar o objeto corretamente?

Comment: Onde está o código de onde você está fazendo o post?

Comment: Pelo o que eu entendi de sua pergunta você quer saber da onde está saindo o POST.
Estou enviando pelo POSTMAN. Vou no headers coloco o Content-type em application/json e descrevo o arquivo na aba Body e dou 'send'

Comment: isso é em asp.net core?

Answer (score 1):

Bom, você está enviando um "objeto" JSON equanto sua `Action` espera uma `string`

**Conteúdo do POST**

```
{
  "Teste":{
  "texto":"teste de post para controller"
   }
}
```

**Sua Action**

```
// POST: api/Teste
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
```

Quando você faz isso, você está realizando o `POST` de `JSON` que representa um `Objeto` que possui outro `Objeto`, chamado `Teste`, que por sua vez possui o `atributo` "texto", onde está declarado o `valor` "teste de post para controller". Enquanto isso na sua Action você simplesmente espera uma string.

A representação correta para esse envio seria criar os objetos para refletirem sua estrutura e "tipar" o parâmetro de entrada da sua `Action`

```
public PostApresentado
{
   public Teste Teste {get;set;}
}    

public Teste
{
   public string Texto {get; set;}
}
```

A sua Action deveria esperar o seguinte input:

```
public void Post([FromBody]PostApresentado value)
{
}
```

E trabalhando dessa forma, você não precisa da `JsonConvert` para serializar e deserializar, isso fica a cargo do framework e você pode trabalhar "diretamente" com os objetos/classes.

Comment: @ABCDEFGH, ficou claro para você??

Answer (score -3):

Se não precisares que seja string podes receber o model ou DTO. Vejo que depois convertes a string para o teu objecto "model" Teste. Acho que tens o mesmo problema que eu tenho. Funciona na app, mas no Postman não. Conseguiste resolver? Preciso tb de enviar pelo Postman um string em vez de json e depois converter também como tu. O Post anterior não percebeu o teu problema, mas eu percebi.